# Область видимости функций в Python

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня есть такой вот метод в файле `fablib.py`:

```
def init(file='production_server.yaml', f_before=before_init, f_after=after_init):
    f_before() # This function will be called from other module
    server = ServerSSH(file) # my class
    server.create_dir()
    server.init()
    f_after() # This function will be called from other module too
```

Далее я создаю файл `fabfile.py`. Как мне сделать в нем функции `f_before` и `f_after` так, чтобы они были видны и вызывались в функции модуля `fablib`?

Запуская скрипт с помощью команды `fab`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Импортировать их в модуле `fablib.py` и установить их в качестве дефолтных значений в функцию `init`.

В файле `fablib.py`:

```
from fabfile import f_before, f_after

def init(file='production_server.yaml', f_before=f_before, f_after=f_after):
    ....
```

Либо вот так:

```
from fabfile import f_before as before_init
from fabfile import f_after as after_init
```